# Constructor Injection with GetIt

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection

I generally write C# enterprise webdev code and am well acquianted with DI, generally using `Microsoft.DependencyInjection`.

Now, I'm trying to set up DI for a Flutter project, `GetIt` seems to be the go-to framework for this.

However, the registration feels so verbose, I feel like I must be missing something.

I don't want to go down the global Service Resolver path for many reasons.

So, do I really have to register everything with every dependency explicitly fetched like this?

```dart
getIt.registerSingleton<MainLayout>(MainLayout(GetIt.instance<PageDefinitionProvider>()));
```

Rather than just having `getIt.registerSingleton<MainLayout>()` and the container will recursively resolve all the dependencies of `MainLayout` for me?

Now, I know Flutter/Dart haven't had reflection for long but surely there must be a better way than this.